# How to fetch data array so i get my data from my server

Tags: android, json

I am trying to fetch data by JSON parsing but unable to fetch the data into my application. kindly help

This is my fetch Data link

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.17//my_home/services/getcategorydata.php?city=Islamabad"); //YOUR PHP SCRIPT ADDRESS 
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();
```

while this is another

```
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();

            result=sb.toString();
```

and finally

```
  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);



       for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
           //dic json call
           //then get data 
           //
           JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


how fetch array of php     


       switch (i)
       {
       case 0:
       {
         Care_title.setText(json.getString("name"));
         Care_minutz.setText(json.getString("rate") );
         child_mintz_.setText(json.getString("hour"));
         break;
       }
       So on....
```

while my php fetch data is

```
{"type":"1","data":[{"name":"Delivery","title":"Delivery","rate":"500 RS","icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/services\/images\/category_icon\n\/delivery.png","publishtype":"PUBLISHED","timestamp":"2015-08-25 12:32:50"},{"name":"Care","title":"Care","rate":"400 RS","icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/services\/images\/category_icon\n\/care.png","publishtype":"PUBLISHED","timestamp":"2015-08-25 12:32:43"}],"title":"Message","message":"","_explicitType":null}
```

Comment: what problem you are getting?

Comment: unable to fetch data using the given link

Comment: hit the `url` in browser and check if you getting something

Comment: yes getting all the data

Comment: also given above in question

Comment: check if your `json ` response contains that `tag` you are looking for.  `json.has("data")`

Comment: I will suggest you to put a break point at `JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);` and debug your application and checkout the the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray dataArray=json.getJSONArray("data");
for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject data=dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name=data.getString("name");
}
```

Comment: not working as I replaced responce with result string

Answer (score 0):

You can use Volley Library for the parsing data.

```
private void JsonCall() throws JSONException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String url = "http://192.168.0.17//my_home/services/getcategorydata.php?city=Islamabad";


    JsonObjectRequest jsonobject = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.PUT, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject arg0) {

            //Your Json Responce
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("Error Code:", arg0 + "");

        }
    })
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonobject, "UPDATETIMELINE");

}
```

Create One application call AppController.java.